# How to filter a collection when binding it to ItemsSource?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, count, treeview

I created a treeview which modelizes directories and files on my hard drive. Each treeviewItem has a checkbox, binded to a isSelected property. What I'd like to achieve is display for each parent node the count of selected files on the total files count (10 / 12 10 files on twelve total selected).

Is there a way to do a binding with where property is ...?

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyItems.Count where MyItems.IsSelected, Mode=OneTime}"
                  Margin="2,0" />
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, I am DHN.

Comment: Can you post your ViewModels or the classes that are bound to the TreeView

Answer (score 16):

There is no way to directly filter the collection in the binding. However, WPF allows filtering (and sorting and grouping) collections with `CollectionViewSource`.

One approach would be to define a `CollectionViewSource` in the resources of your `ItemTemplate` which filters the `ItemsSource` an get the number of elements which pass the filter by binding to the Count property of this `CollectionViewSource`. You have to define your filter in codebehind, though. Would look something like this:

```xml
<TreeView x:Name="Tree" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Resources>
                <CollectionViewSource x:Key="FilteredItems" 
                                        Source="{Binding ChildItems}"
                                        Filter="FilteredItems_OnFilter" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Resources>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{} {0} of {1} selected">
                        <Binding Path="Count" Source="{StaticResource FilteredItems}" />
                        <Binding Path="ItemsSource.Count" ElementName="Tree" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

And in the codebehind:

```
private void FilteredItems_OnFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.Item as Item;
    e.Accepted = item.IsSelected;
}
```

I haven't tested it but it should work in general. You never know with WPF, though...

Comment: What? No need to unit-test this one? Then how do you check that this
functionality works? Automated UI testing? It's a ViewModel's prerogative to contain the current selection, not View's.

Comment: Up-voting because this is the approach shown by WPF authors - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#filtering

Comment: Updated linky @Endrju - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: How you use return with void function ?!, the correct way is to set e.Accepted = true;

Comment: I believe it should be `var item = e.Item as Item;`, because sender is CollectionViewSource.

Answer (score -14):

I personally use the following framework
http://logofx.codeplex.com/
which seems to meet all your requirements (use LogoFX.Mini as it seems enough for your purposes).
Use WrappingCollection.WithSelection as your ItemsSource
Use SelectionCount as the value you want to display.
If you decide not to use the framework, then you should subscribe for selection changed event via dedicated behavior, create dedicated dependency property and update it each time the selection changes.

And one last thing: **Definitely avoid using code-behind**. It breaks the whole MVVM principle.

Comment: -1 - *Definitely avoid using code-behind.* - Come on, that's simply not true. If necessary, you can use code behind. Think on a `CustomControl`, you're not able to implement one without code behind. But there are various other reasons, when code behind is the simplest solution. If you would write **Try when ever you can to avoid using code behind.**, I would be with you.

Comment: +1 for DHN, I consider myself to be quite a MVVM fundamentalist, but that is definitely not true. Behaviors are nothing else than codebehind by btw...

Comment: I distinguish between the controls that are derived from the UserControl (aka views) and the ones that are derived from the Control (aka custom controls). When I speak of code-behind I refer only to the former. And in the case of views the code-behind MUST be avoided. 
How do you even test such a thing if it's build upon code-behind?
If the feature you're trying to implement is pure visual behavior, it's equivalent to implement it in a code-behind (still I see no need for it, because you can do it in either XAML or delegate it to a behavior), if it's something else, you're doing it wrong

Comment: @GenaVerdel Strict, needless and not true. Have you ever tried to fetch the result of a dialog window and pass the value to the VM? There is a simple solution with an event callback or a highly what so ever sophisticated method, involving an `AttachedProperty` and the correct binding. I don't know if you really want to go hard way. If you have only one or two simple dialog go with the code behind. If you have a more complex application go with `AttachedProperty`, because it's worth the effort.

Comment: @DHN. Actually I use the AttachedProperty solution, as this proved to be the best approach. Still, the code-behind does become a rather significant obstacle when it comes to unit-testing the view-model or its parts.

Comment: @GenaVerdel Well since I don't unit test controls, because usually they don't contain a sofisticated logic, I don't see how this would be an obstacle. But yes sure, it means that you have to avoid code behind when ever it's possible and economically avoidable. But let us stop the discussion. I'm not a black or white person, so IMHO you're answer is a way too strict for me. That's all. ;o)